# Run JS function once

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var counter = <?php echo $oak; ?>;
                    function myFunction() {
                        counter++;
                        document.getElementById('countervalue').innerHTML = counter;
                    }
                </script>
```

This function is triggered once an image is clicked on. My problem is that I want it to only trigger the first time the image is pressed. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

html code:

```
<div class="cut_oak_tree">
            <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.outerHTML), myFunction()" /> <!--DO NOT CHANGE SRC -->
            <br>
            <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png " onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.outerHTML), myFunction()" /> <!--DO NOT CHANGE SRC -->
            <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png  " onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.outerHTML), myFunction()" /> <!--DO NOT CHANGE SRC -->
        </div>
```

Comment: How you set this to be called on image click? Show us this code.

Comment: A boolean to keep track of whether it's been clicked?  Remove the click handler from the image?

Comment: Edited html code and good idea^

Comment: @user3287771 instead of removing the click handler you can also edit the function body to do nothing if the flag is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/nd2w3/):

Add `this` on the event call(`onclick="myFunction(this)"`) then your function will looks like `function myFunction(img) {`. Then inside it remove its `click` handler:

```
img.onclick = null;
```

Final result is:

```
function myFunction(img) {
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('countervalue').innerHTML = counter;
    img.onclick = null;
}
```

And an image example:

```
<img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png  " onclick="myFunction(this)" />
```

I wouldn't use a `boolean` like @SLoW suggested because that way you won't be able to know which image was already clicked. To do that you'll have to use an object and store each images `id` - or something like this - and its `clicked` state.

Comment: Nice, it almost worked, my problem is that if you press the image fast enough, it will still count 1 up before the image is removed :o So basically you can get like 5 clicks out of the same tree

Comment: @user3287771 but there's nothing on your post talking about *removing* the image.. so I can't say nothing about it.

Comment: Try moving img.onclick.null above counter++ and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @SLoW that did the job and thanks DontVoteMeDown!

Answer (score 1):

Add a flag

```
function myFunction() {
    if(!myFunction.invoked){
       counter++;
       document.getElementById('countervalue').innerHTML = counter;

       myFunction.invoked = true;
    }
}

myFunction.invoked = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the onclick handler, by sending the element you clicked to the function:

```
<img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png  " onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.outerHTML); myFunction(this)" />

function myFunction(elm) {
    elm.onclick = null; // Remove the onclick
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('countervalue').innerHTML = counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are interested in a jquery approach you can use .one() !
http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
    var counter = <?php echo $oak;?>

    $(".cut_oak_tree img").one("click",function(){
           counter++;
           $("#countervalue").text(counter);   
    });
```

Comment: i hopelessly in love with jquery :P http://designm.ag/resources/5-reasons-why-i-love-and-am-sticking-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

```
// the wrapper that allows to call the inner function only once
function once(inner) {
    var executed = false;
    return function (args) {
        if (executed === false) {
            executed = true;
            inner.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}

// a test function that should only be called once
var inner1 = function (name, age) {
    window.alert("1 " + name + " -> " + age);
}

// another test function
var inner2 = function (name, age) {
    window.alert("2 " + name + " -> " + age);
}

// testing
var wrapped1 = once(inner1);
wrapped1("Tom", 23);
wrapped1("Tina", 24);
wrapped1("Toby", 25);

var wrapped2 = once(inner2);
wrapped2("Tom", 23);
wrapped2("Tina", 24);
wrapped2("Toby", 25);
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear? Ask and I'll try to explain it more. The key point of this solution is, that with `once` you have outsource the problem of making functions only be executable once. It can be reused.

Comment: Looks like this is like the `.one` function from jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: Yeah I have understood but I don't know, it was like *using a bazooka to kill an ant*.

Comment: Well, the only thing needed from my snippet is the topmost function. The rest is only for demonstration purposes. But yes, I would not write it myself, too, since I use underscore.js (which has such a wrapper function and much more).

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a variable called `isClicked`, set it to `false` when the page is loaded, and then set it to `true` when the image is clicked.  Then write an `if` statement to make sure `isClicked` is `false` before incrementing the counter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = <?php echo $oak; ?>;
        var isClicked = false;
        function myFunction() {
            if (isClicked === false){
                isClicked = true;
                counter++;
            }
        document.getElementById('countervalue').innerHTML = counter;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Works perfect, only problem is that I have three images using the same function, it has to count 1 up every time an image is pressed. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you want to track each image's clicks separately?  Going with the boolean approach, perhaps an array of booleans, each one tracking, or use @DontVoteMeDown's approach with passing the img as a parameter to the function and removing the click handler.  That would seem to work.